# How can I control Image texture's frames with a driver?

Tags: image, drivers

I'm a new blender user. I'm trying to drive the *Frames* field (set as 60 here) of an *Image texture* node to control the speed of a *GIF* with some custom properties.

[image]

I've already tried creating a driver on the *Offset* field but this is not doing what I want and I can't create a driver on the *Frames* field.

Is it even possible to add a *Driver* on the *Frames* field? If not, is there another way I can do this?

Comment: can you give more details as to the expression relationship you want? like if *frame* is at 60 what value should appear at *offset*? and if frame=30 what value should offset be?

Comment: I think I didn't express myself well, in the end I want to drive 'Frames' from a custom properties of a bone or an object without changing the 'Offset' value.

Answer (score 3):

You can right click the *Frames* field and select *Copy as New Driver*. Then right click *Offset* field and select *Paste Driver*

[image]

Right click *Offset* field again and select *Edit Driver* and change the *Driver Type* to *Scripted Expression*. In this case, the default *Expression* is `frame_duration`, the variable representation for the *Frames* value (60). Here expression means *Offset* equals *Frames* but you can change this *Expression* to anything you want like `sqrt(frame_duration)+10` or any other [`Math expression`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html)

[image]

Comment: First of all thanks for answer, the problem here is that I don't want to drive the 'Offset' I just took it as an example to show what I wanted on 'Frames'.

Comment: oh sorry the question was confusing. unfortunately you cannot add driver to *Frames* and *Start Frame*. only *Offset*. Your only course of action would be writing a python script in *Scripting Tab*

Comment: Right click *Frame* field and select *Copy Full Data path* to get the python expression to set this field and use it in your python script.

Comment: Yes that’s what I thought I will work on that so ! Thank a lot :)